# What's the right way to handle file permissions for a python app in docker?

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, python-3.6

I'm trying to install a python app on a python3.6 docker base image (linux). I have been trying with a virtual env, despite the fact that some people advise against doing this in docker. I can see that the requirements have been installed in the virtual env's python's site-packages, but when I go to run code from the source directory after activating the virtual env I get a permission error.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /opt

# create a virtual environment and add it to PATH so that it is 
applied for all future RUN and CMD calls (doesn't work)
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install Mono for pythonnet.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes \
    apt-transport-https \
    git \
    dirmngr \
    clang \
    gnupg \
    ca-certificates \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 -- 
recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF \
&& echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian 
stretch/snapshots/5.20 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono- 
official-stable.list \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install --yes \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY src ./src
COPY setup.py ./setup.py
COPY config.json ./config.json
COPY Utility.dll ./Utility.dll
COPY settings.ini ./settings.ini
COPY redis_conf.json ./redis_conf.json
COPY sql_config.json ./sql_config.json

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV \
# From here on, use virtual env's python.
&& venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \

&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \

&& venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir pycparser \

&& venv/bin/pip install -U  --no-cache-dir "pythonnet==2.5.1" \

&& venv/bin/python setup.py install
```

I've checked venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages, and can see that the packages are installed. However when I run this:
venv/lib/python3.6 src/my_app/app.py

I get the following error:
/bin/sh: 3: venv/lib/python3.6: Permission denied

I've tried running chmod +x * when in the lib directory, and the error code changed, but I still got the same error. I'm not sure what I have to do to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: The reason why some people advise against using `venv` in Docker is that a container is a `venv` by itself. If you have a single python application per container (as it should be) then there is no reason in using `venv`. You only make yourself troubles activating it, managing correct Python variables, using `venv/bin/pip` instead of just `pip`, and so on.

Comment: As for the problem, I suggest you have a shell inside the container and try running it manually. For that make sure that your `docker run` command has `-it` keys and `sh` or `bash` at the end.

Comment: What is your image's `CMD`?  How are you starting the container?

Comment: @anemyte I have been trying to run the ap from the container's cli via docker desktop, is that not the same? Do you have a complete example of the run command you mentioned?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have tried several different options and now I just use the cli on docker desktop to eperiment. So far nothing has worked, but the last thing I tried was "cmd  venv/lib/python3.6 src/my_app/app.py"

Comment: @anemyte I tried this: docker run -it app sh, and got the same error.

Comment: Try this `docker run -it --entrypoint="" app sh`. You should see console prompt, then you can try starting the application. If you got the error try using `ls -l venv/lib/python3.6` to see what permissions it has.

Comment: @anemyte wait, what is --entrypoint supposed to be? A path? And what is app? app.py?

Comment: That is to suppress any default commands declared in the image. It's intentionally ="".